# Is there a way to disable the sorting on click within mail.app?

Tags: mail.app, email, sort

Let me first tell you my specific problem:

> I'm setting up mail.app for a senior citizen (read as in bad eyesight,
>   bad hand-eye coordination). I taught a setup were emails would be
>   sorted by newest first. But every other week it happens instead of
>   opening the most recent email some sort column would be clicked (and emails will permanently be sorted in some non-intuitive way).
>   Reproducing the order is a "precision" task the person can not do
>   alone.

So I'm asking is there a hidden option to permanently disable this *feature* (similar to iOS)? 
Or at least what would it take to program some tool that will revert this "setting"?

Answer (score 1):

Someone might know if you can disable the sorting, but if that isn't possible, you can create a keyboard shortcut to switch the sorting back.

Would that be something the user could type?

1. Go to System Preferences / Keyboard / Keyboard Shortcuts /
   Applications.
2. Click the + button.
3. Chose Mail.app
4. Type `Date` into the Menu Title field
5. Select an easy to press and remember combination. (You can't overwrite already existing shortcuts. When I tried this to    test if it would work I used <kbd>command</kbd> <kbd>shift</kbd>    <kbd>D</kbd> )
6. Click "Add" and you are set.

Comment: I will try that. I just will leave the question open for a few more days in hope a permanent solution shows up.